# How to unregister FCM device token and service worker on logout and how to reinitialize the Firebase app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications into my web application (AngularJS). For this I have created one firebase-messaging-sw.js in the root app folder.

```
// firebase-messaging-sw.js
'use strict';
console.log('Starting service worker');

if ('function' === typeof importScripts) {

    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-app.js');
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');
    // importScripts('core/decoder.js');

    // Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
    // messagingSenderId.
    firebase.initializeApp({
        'messagingSenderId': '1043000236721'
    });

    // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
    // messages.
    var messaging = firebase.messaging();


    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
        var shinyData = payload || {};
        var title = 'New Notification';
        console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload, shinyData);

        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: shinyData.body,
            icon: '/resources/images/web-logo.png',
            data: { url: '/#!/home' }
        });
    });

    self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
        var urlToRedirect = event.notification.data.url;
        event.notification.close();
        event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(urlToRedirect));
    });
}
```

and one manifest.json file containing the gcm-sender-id as follows:

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "versionString",

  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800517"

}
```

In the index.html I have initialized Firebase as follows:

```
<script>
        var config = {
            apiKey: "API-key",
            authDomain: "some-authdomain",
            databaseURL: "firebase-databaseUrl",
            storageBucket: "storage-bucketUrl",
            messagingSenderId: "senderId"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
```

With all these configuration the FCM push notifications are working  fine. But the problem is coming when we logout. At the time of logout I am unregistering the service worker as follows:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
                            angular.forEach(registrations, function (registration) {
                                registration.unregister();
                            });
                        });
```

Now, when I try to login again then push notification doesn't works as
after unregistering all the service worker , I am unable to
reinitialise the firebase app.  If I reload the page after logout then
the FCM works perfectly fine as on reload firebase-messaging-sw.js is
loaded again and setup the service worker again.

Please help me to provide the solution for proper logout and login for enabling smooth functioning of FCM.

Comment: Hey yo, did you ever solve this for your case?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tried this solution but I believe this should work.
Write this code in a function as:

```
async function init() {
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
  await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;  
  var config = {
            apiKey: "API-key",
            authDomain: "some-authdomain",
            databaseURL: "firebase-databaseUrl",
            storageBucket: "storage-bucketUrl",
            messagingSenderId: "senderId"
        };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  // getToken and all stuffs
}
```

And call the function `init()` as soon as the user login.

Also, whenever the user logout, you should unregister the service worker with

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
  angular.forEach(registrations, function (registration) {
    registration.unregister();
      });
});
```

Hope this works for you.